# The map path is not displayed on google maps?

Tags: android

The problem that I encountered is that sometimes the path is not displayed which connects 2 points on google maps. but not forever, sometimes it also appears. What should I do? 
this is my code in android

```
private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;


    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;


    return url;
}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Exception while downloading url",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}



// Fetches data from url passed
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }
}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();;
        lineOptions.width(8);
        lineOptions.color(Color.GREEN);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                points.add(position);
            }
            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);

        }
        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        if(points.size()!=0)googleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);//to avoid crash
    }

}
```

how to solve the problem above? Please help me.
or is there a problem with the server that is late accessing?

Comment: Some times person exception occurred, during parsing JSON which is coming from API.More over, it is limited API you need to buy it after it crosses certain limits.

Answer (score 0):

If you get current location using longitude,latitude then implement this method. it will gives you every time onLocationChanged.

```
  @SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility"})
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //      Start implementation for getting current location
            callTrackLocation();
        }

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        private void callTrackLocation() {
            if (latitude != 0.0 && longitude != 0.0 && !country.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                loc_func();
            }

            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    Log.d("Location : ", location.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }
            };

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
                if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                    Log.i(TAG, "onViewCreated: location manager in if condition");
                }
            } else {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //      TODO: Consider calling
                    //      ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    //      here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //      public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)
                    //      to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    //      for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
                    return;
                } else {
                    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onViewCreated: location manager in else if condition");
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                    }
                }
            }

            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (location != null) {
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
            }
            if (latitude != 0.0 && longitude != 0.0) {
                loc_func();
            }
        }

        public void loc_func() {
            Log.i(TAG, "latitude: " + latitude + " longitude : " + longitude);
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                if (addresses != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "latitude: " + latitude + " longitude : " + longitude + "  loc_func : " + addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
                    country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                    String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                    String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                }

                // GetAllQuestionByUser();

                Log.e(TAG, "loc_func: Country : " + country);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```